# Json column - Date field must cast to 'date' in Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a laravel nova panel like below. Im trying to use a Date field like below:

```
new Panel('Suggestions', [
    Flexible::make('Suggestions')
        ->addLayout('Suggestions', 'suggestion', [
            Text::make('Title'),
            Textarea::make('Message'),
            Date::make('Date', 'date')
        ])
        ->button('Add Suggestion'),
]),
```

However it shows this error:

> {message: "Date field must cast to 'date' in Eloquent model.", exception: "Exception",…}
> exception: "Exception"
> file: "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Fields/Date.php"
> line: 41
> message: "Date field must cast to 'date' in Eloquent model."

I have in the model the casts property like this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date'
];
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

I don't have a `date` field on the database table relative to the model. I just have a `suggestions` json field that has a lot of columns including the "`date`" column/key, probably that's the issue. Do you know how to solve this issue in this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your casts instead of 'date' => 'date', this solved for me the issue.

```
protected $casts = [
        'flexible-content' => FlexibleCast::class
    ];
```

Another options is resolving it and converting it to a MomentJS format which also works fine:

```
DateTime::make('Date')
   ->format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
   ->resolveUsing(function ($value) {
           return $value;
   }),
```

source: https://github.com/whitecube/nova-flexible-content/issues/171

Comment: Thanks! Like that it doesn't show the error. Do you know how to change so it have this format "YYYY/MM/DD" and to show the current date by default? Like this is not working :  Date::make('Date')
                        ->format('YYYY/MM/DD')
                        ->resolveUsing(function ($value) {
                                return $value;
                        }),                    ]).

Comment: As per documentation (https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#datetime-field) you could just remove the format because it will default format it to that format, otherwise you could look at Moment.js formatting rules https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ because nova dates standard uses MomentJS for formatting dates

Comment: Thanks but without the format it shows with this format "dd/mm/yyy". And the field shows "dd/mm/yyyy" instead of the current date by default.

Comment: You should take a look then at the MomentJS formatting rules I gave you above, and otherwise you could still transform you date in the resolveUsing with carbon to the needed format. Maybe not the cleanest fix but that should also work.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain how it would work in the resolveUsing()? To have the "yyyy/mm/dd" format?

Comment: replace the return with this:

return Carbon::parse($value)->format(Y-m-d);

This should convert it to the format you need.
source: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-week

Comment: The explenation from the Nova docs: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#field-resolution-formatting

Answer (score 0):

First, I guess you need to rename your db field to something else.

And then

You need to cast your db field into your model like this:

```
//Casts of the model dates
protected $casts = [
    'DB_FIELD_NAME' => 'date'
];
```